# Trying to call a function from another script throws the NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am calling a function from a different script script and I am getting this error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerCollision.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider collision)"
What do I do?
This is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{ 
    
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("BlackSnow"))
        {
            GameManager.Instance.blackSnowEvent(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code in the script where the function is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public ParticleSystem blackSnowParticleSystem;
private bool snowActivated = false;
public int duration = 5;


#region Singleton

private static GameManager instance;

public static GameManager Instance
{
    get
    {
        return instance;    
    }
}


void Start()
{
}

 IEnumerator wait(int arg){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(arg);
}

public void blackSnowEvent(GameObject snowTrigger){
    if(snowActivated == false){

        snowActivated = true;
        snowTrigger.SetActive(false);

        blackSnowParticleSystem.Play();
        Debug.Log(duration);
        StartCoroutine(wait(duration));

        blackSnowParticleSystem.Stop();
       
        snowActivated = false;
    }
} 
#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `GameManager.Instance` is never assigned, so it is null at runtime. You are attempting to invoke the member `blackSnowEvent` on a null reference. To solve, `GameManager.Instance` must be assigned before you attempt to invoke its members

Comment: Thank you! I have done this,
  void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

The error is not because you are calling a method from a different script, it is because you are trying to pass a `null` value as an argument to it.

The error is because in your `if` statement in your `void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)` method, you are trying to check if the collided object has a tag **"BlackSnow"** or not. But that collider doesn't necessarily be something, it may also be null. Hence, Hence modify the `if` statement to this.

```cs
if(collision != null && collision.gameObject.CompareTag("BlackSnow")) {
    GameManager.Instance.blackSnowEvent(blackSnowParticleSystem, collision.gameObject);
}
```

In this scenario, if the compiler detects that the collision object is null, then it doesn't proceed further, therefore doesn't throw any error.

Comment: I have done this:  if(collision != null && collision.gameObject.CompareTag("BlackSnow"))
            {
                GameManager.Instance.blackSnowEvent(collision.gameObject);
            }
an it still gives me the same error, keep in mind that the error happens upon coliding with the trigger.